# SFTP not switching to password mode

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, sshd, ssh-keys

Two servers, synced configs and `ssh` keys. When connecting to the destination, first server switched to the password mode:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
Password Authentication
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

While the second server goes into infinite loop:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [MD5]
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Authenticated with partial success.
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)), explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
....
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: what do you mean by infinite loop? It looks like something that should never happen. What is in server logs?

Comment: well it keeps sending same id_sa key instead of getting Password:   response

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on Red Hat 7, with OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips . I've tried to use an older ssh and sftp binary and it works. The only difference is that I pass through a bluecoat proxy. Could it be a Cipher issue?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the problem was with the ssh client binary:

`OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009`

After copying old ssh binary I am able to connect to the destination server.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the same and it works, but I'd really like to understand why

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly different situation. I have a script which downloads files from remote server by sftp with password authentication (with help of expect). 
When I upgraded OS (Solaris10 x86), sftp suddenly stop ask password :

```
$ sftp -b batches/batch_file login@sftp.server
Permission denied (password).
Connection closed
```

When I added `-o BatchMode=no` to the command line,
the password prompt appeared:

```
$ sftp -o BatchMode=no -b batches/batch_file  login@sftp.server
login@sftp.server's password:
```